# EF5 Select objects based on child collection content

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following case:

```
public Order
{
    ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems {get; set;}
}

public OrderItem
{
    ICollection<ProductReferences> ProdReferences {get; set;}
}
```

and I want to get a collection of all the orders that have a particular product, e.g. something like:

```
Orders.Where(o=>o.OrderItems.Any(oi=>oi.Name.Equals(someName))).ToList();
```

But I want to go one level deeper. As in:

```
Orders.Where(o=>o.OrderItems.Any(oi=>oi.ProdReferences.Any(pr=>pr.Name.Equals(someName)))).ToList();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That looks about right.  Is there an issue with what you have?

Comment: @cadrell0, I updated my question a bit, check it out, sorry for the incomplete first version. ;)

Comment: Do you receive any errors or unexpected results when you try this code?

Comment: I don't receive any results. The collection is just empty. That's the problem, compiling and running the code completes flawlessly.

Comment: Perhaps try `pr.Name == someName` instead of `pr.Name.Equals(someName)`. Does that work?

Comment: Problem is that I have some cases in which I need to use .StartsWith and .EndsWith, so this solution is a dead end for me (haven't tried if it works, can't really, since I have some pretty long names in there).

Comment: Did you try pr.Name.Equals(someName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Orders.Where(
    o => o.OrderItems.Any(
        oi => oi.ProdReferences.Any(
            pr => pr.Name.Contains(someName))));
```

i.e., replace `pr.Name.Equals` with `pr.Name.Contains`.